# __has_cpp_attribute not a 'function-like' macro?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c++14

I am attempting to introduce the `[[deprecated]]` attribute into my codebase. However, not all the compilers I am required to support have support for this syntax yet (the various method used by different compilers before standardization are described in the [attribute standardization proposal N2761](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2761.pdf)). Thus, I am attempting to conditionally compile in this attribute, using the `__has_cpp_attribute` macro-like function first, if it is available, like so:

```
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)
    #define DEPRECATED(msg) [[deprecated(msg)]]
#elif OTHER_COMPILER
    // ...
#endif
```

However, I'm getting errors when compiling this I am using `gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)`, command line `gcc -std=c++14 cpp.cpp`:

```
cpp.cpp:1:56: error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)
```

This error seems to indicate that `__has_cpp_attribute` is defined, but that it is not a macro function. What is the proper way to conditionally compile the `[[deprecated]]` attribute in gcc?

Comment: @T.C. Oh, it doesn't have the feature test macro?

Comment: @Columbo I see in the gcc 5.1 release notes: http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-5/changes.html, it says that `__has_cpp_attribute` was added; so I presume it didn't exist before that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GCC 4.9 doesn't have `__has_cpp_attribute`, and the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` does not extend to allowing invalid constructs to follow it.

That is to say, if `foo` isn't defined,

```
#if defined(foo) && foo(bar)
```

is not valid.

What you want is

```
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) 
    #if __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)
        #define DEPRECATED(msg) [[deprecated(msg)]]
    #endif
#elif OTHER_COMPILER
    // ...
#endif
```

so that the condition using `__has_cpp_attribute` is in a group that is skipped if `__has_cpp_attribute` is not defined. (When in a group that is skipped, preprocessing directives are only processed through the directive's name; the remaining tokens are ignored.)

Answer (score 3):

T.C.'s answer is right, I wanted to add that you can also define a wrapper for `__has_cpp_attribute`, which tends to make multiple tests easier to write

```
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute)
#  define MY_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(attr) __has_cpp_attribute(attr)
#else
#  define MY_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(attr) (0)
#endif

#if MY_HAS_CPP_ATTRIBUTE(attr)
#  define MY_DEPRECATED [[deprecated(msg)]]
#else
#  define MY_DEPRECATED
#endif
```

If you go this route, please use a namespace instead of defining `__has_cpp_attribute`.  Other code will check to see if `defined(__has_cpp_attribute)` and use it if available or fall back on checking compiler versions if it isn't.  Defining `__has_cpp_attribute` will break that.

Of course, a lot of other compilers support some kind of syntax for marking symbols as deprecated even if they don't support `__has_cpp_attribute`, so you'll probably end up with a lot more cases; see the `HEDLEY_DEPRECATED` macro in [Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/).  It currently supports GCC 4.5+, ICC 13+, armcc 4.1+, and TI 7.3+ using the deprecated attribute, MSVC 13.10+ and Pelles 6.50+ using the deprecated declspec, and IAR using a pragma, but it's likely that support will expand over time and I probably won't update this answer.