# Warning C4067 - unexpected token after preprocessor

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

I am using a third party library (PCL), and when compiling it, I get the following warning on an include `warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline`

The code in the header causing this:

```
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated) && !defined(__CUDACC__)
  #define PCL_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
#endif
```

The error line points to the #if defined... line, but I don't understand where that unexpected token(s) is (are).

If I remove everything after the first && (so just keep the has_cpp_) it works. I also tested putting the whole expression in brackets:

```
#if (defined(__has_cpp_attribute) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated) && !defined(__CUDACC__))
  #define PCL_DEPRECATED(message) [[deprecated(message)]]
#endif
```

Then I get an even more confusing `C1012 Corresponding bracket ")" missing` error on that line.

What is happening here?

Comment: If `__has_cpp_attribute` is *not* defined, the preprocessor cannot evaluate the entire line properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402943/has-cpp-attribute-not-a-function-like-macro

Comment: Yeah, it does. That makes sense why it doesn't work with the brackets.